# Do I need to add null-tests everywhere once I have move functions?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, null-pointer

I am not quite sure what the way to go here is; if I have a class with pointer members and a move constructor that sets the pointer members to `nullptr` and the move-functions are the only function that can set the pointer members to 0, do I then need to put tests for zero everywhere I dereference any of the members, as the object might have been passed to a move constructor?

for example, a function

```
unisgned size()
{
    return memberpointer->size();
}
```

would become

```
unisgned size()
{
    if memberpointer == nullptr
        return 0;
    return memberpointer->size();
}
```

Otherwise of course this would give a segfault if `size()` is called on a moved object. Would that be the fault of the user or my fault for not building a null-test? If the user does not access moved object before re-initialising it, this could not happen as long as I put a null-test in the copy assignment operator:

```
C& operator=(C& src)
    {
        if (this != &src)
        {
            if (memberpointer == nullptr)
                init();
            *memberpointer = *src.memberpointer;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Putting test for null everywhere would reduce performance, which would be unnecessary if the user knew that accessing a moved and not re-initialized object is undefined behavior.
What is the way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no need for all those tests, any more than if you didn't have move semantics at all.  If it's illegal to use your object before calling some sort of initialization function, then you should also consider it illegal to use the object after moving.  Your object should be left in a state that can be properly destructed, but there are no other rules specifying what that state should be.

For example:

```
Foo foo;
foo.Init();  // required
// foo is now allowed to be used

Foo bar = std::move( foo );
// No guarantees on whether foo is now initialised or not.
```

Move semantics do not stipulate what state the object moved *from* will be in after the move.  It only requires the object is in some internally consistent state.  So, your move constructor or assignment operator is perfectly entitled to *swap* the members if it wishes...  Provided all the other internal states of the object are consistent with that.  That is, it's perfectly okay to have this situation:

```
Foo foo, bar;
foo.Init();
bar.Init();
bar = std::move( foo );
// foo and bar contents now swapped.
// caveat: you should not use foo again
```

However, you must not *expect* this.  The rule is that after a move, you should not attempt to use the object again.

Comment: What if `init()` was a private function called from constructors only? Your explanation seems based on the assumption `init()` or any function like that existed as a public function, whilst I just put it in my example to abstract away from the initialization of an unspecified number of members.

Comment: Well yeah, that was totally the assumption.  But the same holds if it's private.  So let's say your object expects that `init` is always called from the constructor.  You could code naively and make the move constructor invoke `init` and then swap all the members with the target.  But hopefully you'll now realise that because the object can be left in an unspecified state, nobody can complain if you crash after trying to use it post-move.  The only thing you _do_ need to ensure is that the destructor has defined behaviour even if `init` was never called (and pointer members are all NULL).

Comment: This is why swap is quite a common approach for moves: You simply switch everything out, and you know that both objects will be in a valid state.  This means you don't have to do tricky things like duplicate parts of the constructor and/or destructor logic in your move constructor.  In fact, some will actually implement `swap` for their class to do exactly this, and then invoke it directly for moves: `C::C( C && c ) { std::swap( *this, c ); }`

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard library solves this by leaving the moved-from object in a "valid but unspecified" state: In other words you can operate on it, using it won't crash your program, but the only predictable thing to do is write to it to re-establish a known state.

If your default constructor doesn't leave the pointers null, then your move constructor shouldn't either: It should leave the move-from object in a state where you can safely call members on it but not rely on any particular values. If your default constructor leaves the pointer(s) null then obviously that's fine for the move constructor too.

Comment: But then I would need to reinitialize the members with a `memberpointer = new T` after moving from them, would I not?

Comment: @lotolmencre: So just make a copy? It's unclear since you're not showing any real code.

Comment: So the answer is actually depending on whether or not the memberPointer can be null, which is a design decision that have to be made by the author?

Comment: Not quite.  If you want to use that identifier, you should move a new _empty_ value into it first, and then initialise.  And that means, yes: if initialise will call `new` for some members.  _i.e._ `C c2 = std::move(c1); c1 = std::move(C());`